# Mean of a function of exponential distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

Let $X$ a random variable exponentially distributed, compute:
$$E[ {1}_{\{X>t\}}X]$$
I think that it can be computed as function of a random variable, but my answer was different of answer given. I Think that:

$$E[ {1}_{\{X>t\}}X]=\int_t^\infty x\lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx$$

Comment: Please show us your calculations, then we can tell you where you have made a mistake.

Comment: What was the result of your calculation, and what was the answer given?

Comment: So far, your equation is correct. How did you evaluate the integral?

Comment: I found my error, I was computing incorrectly the integral. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have figured it out. But to summarize the unanswered question,
$$E[ {1}_{\{X>t\}}X]=\int_t^\infty x\lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx$$
Integrate by parts or do as follows:

$$\begin{align}
\int_t^\infty x\lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx&=-\lambda\int_t^\infty \frac{d}{d\lambda}\left( e^{-\lambda x}\right) dx\\
&=-\lambda\frac{d}{d\lambda}\left(\int_t^\infty  e^{-\lambda x}dx\right) \\
&=-\lambda\frac{d}{d\lambda}\left(\frac{e^{-\lambda x}}{-\lambda}\biggr\vert^{\infty}_t\right)\\
&=-\lambda\frac{d}{d\lambda}\left(\frac{e^{-\lambda t}}{\lambda} \right)\\
&=-\lambda\frac{-\lambda te^{-\lambda t}-e^{-\lambda t}}{\lambda^2}\\
&=\frac{(1+\lambda t)e^{-\lambda t}}{\lambda}
\end{align}$$